# How to install osm2pgrouting on Windows?

Tags: windows, osm2pgrouting

I've only done networking using ArcGIS, but am now trying to set up with OpenSource software in a Windows environment.  I have PostGIS installed and found a Windows binary for pgRouting (although I'm not clear on how to install this).  I now need to get OSM data ready for pgRouting and osm2pgrouting seems to be the way to go.  However, I can only find instructions for installation on Ubuntu.  Can anybody help me with an idiot's guide to compiling and installing osm2pgrouting on windows please?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are still open for other suggestions, I'd recommend osm2po instead of osm2pgrouting because in my experience it works without size limitations. It's also very easy to install. I've written a [short how-to part 1](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/an-osm2po-quickstart/) & [part2](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/osm2po-part-2-pgrouting-on-osm-the-easy-way/) a while ago.

I've also written a [guide on installing pgRouting on Windows](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/) which should help you install the binaries you downloaded.

Comment: Superb!  I am always open to alternative suggestions (since I regularly make them myself!).  I will check this out.  I found osm2po and liked the look of it but was put off because the documentation was in German.  I thought I'd ask here before I tried working off a Google translation (which could get "interesting").  Your "how to" looks helpful so I will follow that.  Thanks for taking the time to share it.

Comment: In case anybody else is looking for this solution, can I add a little hint to underdark's excellent "how to".  Avoid spaces in your path to osm2po.  I put mine under "C:\Program Files\" and got a fatal error.  Osm2po could not find the path to the subfolder it tries to create using your prefix.  Moving osm2po to a location with no spaces fixed the issue and it is now running happily as I type.