# How to restart an osm2po service from a previous run?

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2po

I have followed underdark's clear and concise ["how to"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21253/how-to-install-osm2pgrouting-on-windows) to get osm2po running.  The web service is a great little tool for inspecting the data.  Is there a way to restart the service using an existing run after closing the command prompt (i.e. stopping the service)?

I'm guessing there is a way to do this without having to convert all the OSM data a second time.  However, the documentation is in German so I can't tell.

Many thanks

Comment: Tipp:
There is an english on-screen help (draft) for upcoming versions on the web page.

Comment: Excellent!  Looking forward to it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by modifying the `cmd=` parameter. By default the value is `tjsgpr` (Tiler|Joiner|Segmenter|Postprocessors|Graph-builder|Routing). `cmd=c` is short form of `cmd=tjsp`.

In the German documentation there is a table around page 15 explaining each command. Only for `t` (Tiler) for example you need to pass the data source URL or path, `j` depends on `t`, `s` depends on `j`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**grtjsp** is the same as **grc**

**c** is just a shortcut for **tjsp**