# Which version of pgRouting should I use with PostgreSQL 9.1 and PostGIS 2.0 (on win xp)?

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I am new to GIS.
I want to install pgRouting on my system (win-xp 32-bit). I am trying to run routing_core.sql file and got the following error:
ERROR:  incompatible library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/librouting.dll": version mismatch
DETAIL:  Server is version 9.1, library is version 8.4.
What should I do for proper installing of pgRouting ?
Thanks for your suggestion/comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the situation for 9.1, but here is a recent pledgebank thread about pgRouting for Win Postgres 9.2+ http://www.pledgebank.com/pgRoutingWindows.

The safest bet right now is to get Postgres 8.4.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Madam Underdark!! I have seen your tutorials and Blogs. They are extremely helpful and full of knowledge for all kind of users.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to install osm2pgrouting on Windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21253/how-to-install-osm2pgrouting-on-windows) - you can find instructions on how to get pgRouting with Postgres 9.1 working (actually provided there link has both x32/64 versions of pgRouting Windows binaries)